# $B$-$L$ global symmetry in the grand unification theories

Tags: particle-physics, symmetry, standard-model, beyond-the-standard-model, grand-unification

- What are the precise [$B$-$L$ (baryon - lepton) global symmetry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B_%E2%88%92_L) in the standard model?
- Is this a $U(1)$ global symmetry or a discrete finite group $\mathbb{Z}/N$ global symmetry for the following examples?

Does the precise $B$-$L$ global symmetry present in:

- [SU(5) Georgi–Glashow model grand unification theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Georgi%E2%80%93Glashow_model)? If so, how does the $B$-$L$ global symmetry  act on the fermion representations $\bar{5}$ and $10$?
- [$SO(10)$ grand unification theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SO(10)_(physics))? If so, how does the $B$-$L$ global symmetry  act on the fermion's spinor representations $16$?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the standard model lagrangian, *B* and *L* are separately conserved global charges, and *B-L*, a vector like symmetry, is anomaly-free. GUTs, like the G-G SU(5) violate *B* and *L*, but preserve *B-L*.

Wikipedia effectively defines the SU(5)-model *U(1)* symmetry *X* as 
$$X = 5(B − L) -2Y_W,
$$
introduced by [Wilczek & Zee in 1979](https://journals.aps.org/prl/pdf/10.1103/PhysRevLett.43.1571?casa_token=EzlMo4dWblcAAAAA%3AFeKmYx0C-5tGuXBGQP66MHMdJFoPUZ_lkmrPe4xYQOJQZ-ceCaWVuC8OC7yVurKysq4gBoRZFTbolQ). 
It is *not* a generator of SU(5), of course.

So you may readily compute for the left-chiral $\bar {\bf{5}}$,
$$
\overline{ d_R} : ~~(2Q=)~~~ Y=2/3  , ~~~~ B-L= -1/3 ~~~ \leadsto X=-3 \\
e^-_L, \nu_L : ~~~~~~~ Y= -1  , ~~~~~~ B-L= -1 \qquad \leadsto X=-3.
$$ 
So the entire multiplet possesses a common X-charge:  -3.

Proceed to verify for the left-chiral **10**, X= 1. 
$$
\overline{ u_R} : ~~(2Q=)~~~~~ Y=-4/3  , ~~~~ B-L= -1/3  ~~~\leadsto X=1 \\  d_L,u_L : ~~~~~~~~~ Y=1/3  , ~~~~ B-L= 1/3 \qquad \leadsto X=1
\\
e^+_L  : ~~(2Q=)~~~~~ Y=  2  , ~~~~~~~ B-L= 1 \qquad \leadsto X=1.
$$

Thence, for the $\langle \phi ^* \rangle$, *X=2*, so the Yukawa (mass) term is chargeless.

Note that *B-L* is vectorlike, but *Y* is not, so, ipso facto, *X* is not!

Similarly for SO(10), except here *X* is now a generator of SO(10) and is then gauged (hence SSBroken), hence violated by small amounts.

---

*Responses to comment questions*.

1) B-L is a good global symmetry for the SM and  SU(5) and local for SO(10). So, e.g., in SU(5) proton decay to a pion and a positron, it is visibly preserved!

2) *X* is fine  in the SM and SU(5) as a global symmetry, as a linear combination of good quantum numbers. As defined, it has a unique eigenvalue for each SU(5) rep, not necessarily the same for all reps, as you observe. Same for the SM which has smaller reps, several of which entered into  each SU(5) rep.  That means that, even for SU(5) which mixes baryons and leptons, it is straightforward to match *X* eigenvalues and monitor the symmetry of the coupling terms, like the Yukawas.

3) SO(10) largely follows suit, paralleling SU(5), and likewise lacks exotic particles, but gauges *X*, so SSBreaks it. But now the above two reps of SU(5) plus an extra singlet (the R-chiral neutrino) fit into a spinor 16 of SO(10). If your wrote down the multiplet, it might be easier to parse out.  [This review](https://s3.cern.ch/inspire-prod-files-3/321cbbb269249974777435b95552a46f), eqn. (3.3), has *X* as a traceless diagonal generator, so you can check its eigenvalue on the fermion 16-plet (4.2).

Now, in most models, even though *X* is SSBroken and its corresponding gauge boson made massive, this happens at a high scale and results in a GUT with SU(5)-like symmetry, with effective B-L violating operators of dimension 6, i.e. suppressed by the square of such heavy scales, so very small. Thus, in such models, for all intents and purposes, proton decay is still approximately respectful of B-L!

Comment: Thanks, I vote up. So B, L and B-L are all global symmetry in standard model. Agree?

Comment: But B, L are not global symmetry in SU5 or SO10 models. And B-L is a global symmetry in SU5 or SO10 model. Agree?

Comment: Yes, to both, as indicated at the beginning. B,L, and B-L are SM global symmetries, although anomalies violate B and L, preserving B-L. Most GUTs violate B and L, but preserve B-L, and of course Y (in the SM), as in G-G proton decay. Have you clicked the checkmark?

Comment: also can B-L symmetry be adiscrete symmetry in standard models, SU5 or SO10? or some of the Proposed GUTs? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grand_Unified_Theory#Proposed_theories

Comment: In SM, SU(5), and   SO(10)  it is a fine continuous (Lie) symmetry, not just discrete, so why focus on a subgroup, if you have the full enchilada? I am not sure there is a general theory of GUTs --it is always it or miss. They usually have *extra fermions* for a change, so I don't know how one assigns B and L numbers to those. But, where there is a will, there is a way; recall Gell-Mann--Ramond--Slansky? The ones you link to, however, are truly bad make-work projects. This might be a separate question.

Comment: Dear Sir, I accept the answer. However I am still puzzled a bit. Are we saying that:

Comment: 1) The B-L is a global symmetry in standard models. But B-L is NOT a global symmetry for SU(5) and SO(10) g.u.t.?

Comment: 2) The X is a global symmetry in SU(5). But X is NOT a global symmetry for standard models and SO(10) g.u.t.?

Comment: 3) what are the modified "B-L" in  SO(10) g.u.t. then?

Comment: p.s. the reason I said 1), is because that the $\bar{5}$ and 10 each of them do not carry the same B-L, but each of them does carry the same X sym

Comment: "B-L is a symmetry in SU(5), so proton decay to a pion and a positron" "B-L is gauged in for SO(10)", so what happened to proton decay in SO(10)?

Comment: When we say $G$ is a global symmetry with a symmetry group $G$, we mean that we should be able to find  gauge invariant charged operator that carry the symmetry charge.

Comment: Continued - However, for $G=U(1)_{B-L}$, all the charged operator that carry the symmetry charge given as the  5¯ and 10 above, or other representations like 16, they are all gauge non-invariant fields/operator. If so, how can we say $G=U(1)_{B-L}$ is a global symmetry? Can we identify other gauge invariant fields/operator charged under the $G=U(1)_{B-L}$?

Comment: Otherwise, should we say $G=U(1)_{B-L}$ is gauged in SU(5) g.u.t? Thank you~

Comment: No! Global means not gauged! In G-G, the U(1) charges in a rep sum to not 0, so not traceless, so not part of the SU(5) gauge group.

Comment: Yes, thanks, but 5¯ and 10 are also gauged under SU(5). Should the best way to describe the (1)$_{−}$ is finding the gauge-invariant operators (gauge-invarian field contents) that transform nontrivially under the (1)$_{−}$? but transform trivially under SU(5)?

Comment: p.s. thus 5¯ and 10 are not the best to describe the (1) − global symmetry?

Comment: $U(1)_{B-L}$ generators/charges commute with SU(5) gauge generators, and are, of course, SU(5)  singlets, made up of bilinears $\bar 5 \cdot 5$ and $\bar 10 \cdot 10$, manifestly gauge invariant.

Comment: many thanks, almost clear. But 5¯⋅5  and 10¯⋅10 are in trivial representation of (1)−,  yes or no? If so, one needs to find gauge invariant non-trivial representation of (1)−. I think five of 5, say 55555, and ten of 10 can do the job?

Comment: No, think of the electric charge operator. It generates U(1) rotations and is also an EM singlet, and a color singlet, etc...

Comment: B-L is a good global symmetry for the SM, agree. But $U(1)_{B-L}$ does not transform SU(5)'s representation $5¯$ and $10¯$ in a uniformed manner, even under each multiplet. How can I get convinced that B-L is a good global symmetry for SU(5) g.u.t?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107036/discussion-between-cosmas-zachos-and-annie-heart).

Comment: I see, X is the $U(1)_{B-L}$ for the G-G theory. The original $U(1)_{B-L}$ is not global symmetry for the G-G theory, yes?

Comment: Is that $e^+_L=\overline{e^-}_R$ always true in QFT?

Comment: On your right hand side, the R should be *inside* the overbar, so it turns to an L as it slips past the $\gamma^0$ thereof, and the two sides have the same chirality. Beyond that, yes, of course. It’s not in your text?

Comment: Excuse me - I come back to read you said but got confused "SO(10), except here X is now a generator of SO(10) and is then gauged (hence SSBroken), hence violated by small amounts."

Comment: --> (1) how can the $X$ which acts on $16= \bar{5}+10$ above differently, say $X=-3$ for  $\bar{5}$ and $X=1$ for $10$ ---- can still be a generator of SO(10)?Can you clarify?

Comment: --> (2) If this $X$ is gauged, then how is that SSBroken? (which group is SSBroken? down to which group?)

Comment: --> (3) why violated by small amounts? can you give a ref?

Comment: You said "1) B-L is a good global symmetry for the SM and SU(5), and local for SO(10)." But I understood differently as

Comment: --> (4)  B-L is a good global symmetry for the SM. But  B-L is NOT a global symmetry for the SU(5) GG. Only X is a global symmetry for the SU(5) GG. Do you agree? X is not B-L.

Comment: --> (5) I do not see how the B-L nor the X be a good symmetry generator act on the 16 of  SO(10). So I regard that B-L and X are NOT good symmetry of  SO(10). Do you agree?

Comment: I think the Wilczek & Zee ref in [here](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/0370269380903147)   and Ozer's thesis linked above should answer all questions. B-L is the difference of two SU(5) and SO(10) generators.

Comment: (1) X is not a diagonal operator for the 16 of SO(10): different components are acted upon differently. (2) SO(10)-->SU(5). (4) (B-L) is a linear combination of two SU(5) GG symmetries, X global and Y local. (5) They are good symmetries as generators, in Ozer's thesis.

Comment: -thanks a lot -!

Comment: [WP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_(charge)).

Comment: thanks Cosmos, btw I do NOT think X (or 5(B - L)- 2 Y) in SO(10) GUT is a continuous U(1) group. It shall be a discrete group, is that true?

Comment: These are Lie group generators generating Noether currents. Why discrete?

Comment: I think X (or 5(B - L)- 2 Y)  in SO(10) GUT is at the $Z_4$ center of Spin(10), which is discrete. I am not sure there is any concrete way to embed the U(1) outside of SU(5) to Spin(10) in the way that people said to have the continuous U(1) for X, at least not for the SO(10) GUT with the Spin(10) group ...

Comment: Ask a separate question, but be explicit.

Comment: thanks - I will <3

Comment: I propose that (2)⊃(1)×() is false for n=5. See  math.stackexchange.com/q/3727359/141334 ? Agree? if so, (or 5(B - L)- 2 Y) is not continuous in $Spin(10)$

Comment: [Slansky Table 14](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.126.1581&rep=rep1&type=pdf), the starting point of any and all such questions, as your instructor in your GUT course ***must*** have emphasized to you.

Comment: but those Table seem to include only Lie algebra, I am not sure they have Lie group consideration included. Thank you a good ref I just learned from you!

Comment: btw I have one more basic puzzle learning GUT: physics.stackexchange.com/questions/560676

Comment: maybe you also know already physics.stackexchange.com/questions/564976

Comment: Don't know much about its [advantages](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S037026930401617X). Gives you longer life for the proton...